# Celery not consuming tasks when queue name is specified

Tags: python, docker, celery

I have 2 different tasks defined and I would like to route each task to its corresponding queue. However, when I try to specify a queue using the `-Q` option, the tasks do not get consumed by Celery. However, everything works as expected if I run without the `-Q` option. I am using `celery==4.2.0`

Am I missing any configuration or setting something up in a wrong manner?

I'm using `docker-compose.yml` to run each queue in a different container.

`docker-compose.yml` <-- does not work since `-Q` is specified

```
version: '3'
services:
  broker:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    environment: &envfile
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: user
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: password
      CELERY_BROKER: {something}
      RABBITMQ_BACKEND: {something}

    ports:
      - 5672:5672

worker1:
    build: .
    image: worker1
    restart: "always"
    command: ["celery", "worker", "--app=worker.app", "--concurrency=4", "--hostname=worker1@%h", "--loglevel=INFO", "-Q", "queue1"]
    depends_on:
      - broker
  
worker2:
    build: .
    image: worker2
    restart: "always"
    environment: *envfile
    command: ["celery", "worker", "--app=worker.app", "--concurrency=4", "--hostname=worker2@%h", "--loglevel=INFO", "-Q", "queue1"]
    depends_on:
      - broker

scheduler:
    build: .
    image: scheduler
    restart: "always"
    environment: *envfile
    command: ["celery", "beat", "--app=worker.app", "--loglevel=INFO"]
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - worker1
      - worker2
```

My file structure is as follows:

```
├── rootfolder
│   ├── worker
│        ├── celery.py
│        ├── tasks.py
│        ├── schedule.py
│        ├── __init__.py
└──
```

`celery.py`

```
from celery import Celery
import os

app = Celery(
    'worker',
    broker=os.environ['CELERY_BROKER'],
    backend=os.environ['RABBITMQ_BACKEND']
)

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "get-message": {
        "task": "worker.get_message_list",
        "schedule": 60
    },
    "get-somethingelse": {
        "task": "worker.get_something_list",
        "schedule": 60
    }
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

Comment: The way you configured Celery beat, those two tasks are sent to the default queue ("celery"). Since your worker(s) are subsribed to a different queue ("queue1"), there are no workers to execute tasks sent to the "celery" (default) queue, so they are just waiting in the queue until there is at least one worker subsribed to the default queue to pick them up... To fix this, modify the beat_schedule to send those two tasks to the "queue1" queue.